Why am I unable to connect a webservice with tlsv1.2 protocol?
I need to access a web service using C# and so far everything has worked well. Recently they changed the security protocol to TLSV1.2 and so I can no longer access it with the following return:

Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The underlying
connection was closed: Unexpected error on a send. --->
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from transport connection:
An existing connection was forced to be canceled by the remote host.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forced to be canceled by the remote host

My code is
      class Program
          {
              public static string arquivopfx;
              public static string senha;
              
              public static void Main(String[] args)
              {
            
              int counter = 0;  
              string line;  

              System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"assina.config");  
              while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)  
              {  
                  if (counter == 3)  
                  {
                    break;
                  }
                  if (counter == 0)  
                  {
                    arquivopfx = line;
                  }
                  if (counter == 1)  
                  {
                    senha = line.Trim();
                  }
                  counter++;  
              }  
              file.Close();
              Execute();
              }

              /// <summary>
              /// Execute a Soap WebService call
              /// </summary>
              /// doc.Save("c:\\try.xml");
              
              public static void Execute()
              {
                  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;            

                  HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest();
                  XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
                  soapEnvelopeXml.Load(@"SOAP_request.xml");
                  soapEnvelopeXml.PreserveWhitespace = true;            
                  request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                  
                  try {

                    File.Delete(@"SOAP_response.xml");

                    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
                    }
                    
                    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8")))
                        {
                            // ljê a resposta para uma string
                            string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                            Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
                            // grava a string no disco
                            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("SOAP_response.xml", false, Encoding.Default))
                            {
                                writer.WriteLine(soapResult);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  }
                  catch (WebException ex)
                  {
                      //string message = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                      throw ex;    
                  }
              }
              /// <summary>
              /// Create a soap webrequest to [Url]
              /// </summary>
              /// <returns></returns>
              public static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest()
              {
                  string url = "https://webservices.envio.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc";
                  HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                  webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction","http://www.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_0/ServicoEnviarLoteEventos/EnviarLoteEventos");
                  webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
                  webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
                  webRequest.KeepAlive = false;            
                  webRequest.Method = "POST";
                  webRequest.Timeout = 30000;
                  webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(arquivopfx, senha));            
                  return webRequest;
              }
          }


I think you mean the server went from TLS 1.2 to TLS 1.3.  TLS 1.2 is very old.  What OS are you using?  Either you need to add a new certificate to support TLS 1.3, or you OS is very old and doesn't support the encryption mode being used with the TLS 1.3 certificate.

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = why is this line here? Get rid of it, and rely on the OS to specify the TLS version. @jdweng TLS1.2 is not that old, there are still many servers getting rid of TLS1.1 and below. You don't need a new cert for TLS1.3, the cert type is immateral to the TLS version.

Sorry, my OS is Windows 10 pro; Netframework 4.7

@Charlieface : The OP code recently stopped working.  For the last 6 years only TLS 1.2 and 1.3 are valid.  Very unlikely that OP was using the obsolete versions of SSL and TLS.

@jdweng Given the code I pointed out, and that there are still many webservers which allow TLS1 and TLS1.1, and the fact that almost nobody ever disables LS1.2 (why would you, it's not insecure) it's definitely not TLS1.2 being disabled that's the issue, it's almost certainly a lower version or a cipher suite that's been disabled.

My cipher suite is updated and according with the needs of the webservice

Change to : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls2 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls3;   There is no harm is using TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3 in this case.  Check the csproj file using notepad and make sure you are using the OS for TLS (not Net).  Follow best practice here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#for-httpclient-and-httpwebrequest

By having ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3; in your code, you are forcing it to use either SSL 3.0 or TLS 1.0. Both are considered deprecated and should no longer be used.
Microsoft recommends that you don't specify which TLS/SSL versions to use. This way, the choice will be left to the OS.
